The SVG label starts moving along the path with a delay after the block is displayed on the screen
I have a block that appears on the screen with a delay. There are 3 PNG images and an inscription on SVG in the block. Around one image, an inscription made in SVG moves along the contour. After the block is displayed on the screen, the PNG images appear normally, but the inscription does not start moving immediately (the delay is about two seconds). See how it works here https://codepen.io/bsi_52/pen/dyLKggM. Here's the code^:
<div class="hide_block2" id='ContButilka'>
   
   <img class="butilka" src="https://habrastorage.org/webt/7i/mp/vj/7impvjl59tcl9vnfcswnorizeie.png" alt=""/>
<img class="stakan_l" src="https://habrastorage.org/webt/wr/h0/jt/wrh0jtev85sz0b8kdw5sk6pqfx4.png" alt=""/>

  <img class="stakan_p" src="https://habrastorage.org/webt/wr/h0/jt/wrh0jtev85sz0b8kdw5sk6pqfx4.png" alt=""/>

<div class="text_nadpis">
<svg
            id="svg1"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
            viewBox="0 0 170 280"
            width="300"
            height="500"
        >
            <defs>
                <path
                    id="path1"
                    d="m 119.81679,209.71055 -1.74551,1.62083 -1.99487,0.74808 -1.87019,0.12468 -1.74551,0.24936 h -1.74551 -1.87019 -1.37147 -0.74808 l -1.24679,0.24935 h -0.99743 l -1.74551,0.12468 -0.74808,-0.24936 h -0.37404 -0.87275 l -0.997435,-0.12467 h -1.246793 l -1.246793,-0.12468 -2.244228,-0.37404 -1.37147,-0.37404 h -0.748078 l -0.498716,-0.12468 -0.498718,-0.49872 -1.246791,-0.49871 -0.374039,-0.37404 -0.374038,-0.37404 -0.249357,-0.74808 v -0.87275 l 0.124677,-0.87275 0.12468,-0.87276 -0.12468,-1.24679 v -0.74808 -0.74808 l 0.12468,-0.49871 -0.12468,-0.6234 h -0.124677 v -0.37404 l 0.374036,-0.49871 0.374039,-1.24679 0.12468,-44.75987 0.249356,-16.8317 -0.498716,-0.99743 -0.249359,-0.87276 0.249359,-2.36891 0.12468,-1.74551 0.249359,-0.87275 0.249357,-1.37147 0.249359,-0.99744 0.997434,-1.62083 0.872755,-2.49358 0.623398,-1.62083 0.249356,-0.87276 0.498719,-1.49615 0.623395,-1.24679 0.374039,-0.87276 0.623395,-1.24679 0.374039,-1.24679 0.374039,-1.2468 0.623395,-0.99743 0.374039,-1.49615 0.12468,-0.6234 0.249356,-1.37147 0.872755,-0.99743 0.124679,-2.61827 V 85.405308 l 3.116983,-0.872754 1.87019,-0.24936 1.99487,0.24936 h 1.74551 0.87275 l 1.49615,0.623395 v 22.442271 l 7.10672,19.94869 1.37147,2.9923 0.49872,1.62083 v 1.24679 l 0.24936,2.49358 -0.12468,1.62084 -0.49872,0.37403 0.49872,63.58644 0.49872,0.49871 z"
                    fill="none"
                    stroke="none"
                />
            </defs>
 
            <text
                id="txt1"
                lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs"
                textLength="40%"
                font-size="13"
                font-weight="bold"
         >   
                <textPath
                    id="result1"
                    method="align"
                    spacing="auto"
                    startOffset="-25%"
                    xlink:href="#path1"
                >
                    <tspan dy="-" fill="yellow">Да наливай уже!</tspan>
                    <animate
                        id="a1"
                        dur="12s"
                        attributeName="startOffset"
                        values="-25%;119%"
                        begin="0s;a1.end+5s"
                    />
                </textPath>
            </text>
 
            <text
                id="txt1"
                lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs"
                textLength="40%"
                font-size="13"
                font-weight="bold"
            >
                <textPath
                    id="result2"
                    method="align"
                    spacing="auto"
                    startOffset="-25%"
                    xlink:href="#path1"
                >
                    <tspan dy="-2" fill="yellow">Да наливай уже!</tspan>
                    <animate
                        id="a2"
                        dur="12s"
                        attributeName="startOffset"
                        values="-25%;119%"
                        begin="8.5s;a2.end+5s"
                    />
                </textPath>
           </text>
 

        </svg>

   </div>

#ContButilka {
 grid-row: 1;
grid-column: 1;
   width: 100%;
margin-top: 30px;
margin-left: 1em;
max-width: 200px;
position: relative;
display: none;   
}

.text_nadpis {
grid-row: 1;
grid-column: 1;
position: relative;
margin-top: -35.2em;
margin-left: 20.25em;
}
 
.butilka {
grid-row: 1;
grid-column: 1;
transform: scale(0.85);
position: relative;
margin-top: 1em;
margin-left: 25.5em;
} 

.stakan_l {
grid-row: 1;
grid-column: 1;
position: relative;
top: -6em;
margin-left:23em;
} 

.stakan_p {
grid-row: 1;
grid-column: 1;
position: relative;
top: -10.6em;
margin-left:33.5em;
} 
 

setTimeout(function() {
   document.getElementById('ContButilka').style.display = 'block';
}, 3000);




the only delay I see anywhere is the 3 second delay due to your setTimeout - but that's in Firefox

In the code, there is one delay of 3 seconds. Look at the link, there you can see that there are 3 PNG images, a nldpiss appears around the middle image and it begins to move along the contour not immediately, but after a certain period of time. You need to make sure that the movement of the label starts from the same time as the block is displayed.

You need to make sure that the movement of the label starts from the same time as the block is displayed - no, that's what YOU need to do - as I said, there is no delay for me at all - though there is a nasty glitch with the last 3 characters of the text appearing too soon
